# Execute stored procedures in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library

I have these 2 methods

```
public DataTable GetData1(int Id)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetData1", sqlcon))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@id", Value = Id});

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }

    return dt;
}

public DataTable GetData2(int Id)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetData2", sqlcon))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@id", Value = Id});

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

and I would like to execute them at once and also get the data for further processing.

I tried something like

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => database.Data.GetData1(1));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => database.Data.GetData2(2));

var taskList = new List<Task> { task1, task2 };

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

but on the last line it crashes with

> there is one or more errors.`

The inner exception is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack trace

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The `connectionString` is obtain from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database` class

```
 public class DatabaseRepository : IDisposable
    {
        DbContext dbContext;

        public DatabaseRepository()
        {
             dbContext = new DbContext("connection string ...");
             Data = new DataRepository(dbContext.Database);

        }
        public DataRepository Data { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

but the error is the same even i set connection string manually, so i dont think the error is here.

```
   using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("connection string ..."))
   {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetData2", sqlcon))
      {
       ...
      }
   }
```

How can I do that? I see some examples use `Async` return type, but I don't want to duplicate these methods.

Comment: Can you show how `database` is declared? It may not be safe to access it concurrently. Also, the full error message you receive would be helpful. Keep in mind too, `Task.WaitAll` is going to block waiting for your two tasks, so offloading them hasn't gotten you much. You could turn that method into `async` and `await Task.WhenAll`

Comment: You should investigate the `InnerException` for the exception you got, as it is a wrapper `AggregateException` with no actual error information

Comment: You're not opening your connection. I'd be willing to bet that's your exception.

Comment: @Cameron, he's using `SqlDataAdapter` which opens the connection automatically.

Comment: @JSteward database is object of `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` but iam reading only connection string from that object so I think it should not matter ?

Comment: @VMAtm I updated question with inner exception, it says that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: And what's the stack trace?

Comment: @VMAtm The stack trace is at the `database.Data.GetData1(1)` but i dont see any errors there ?! But the procedure works if executed normally. Maybe the procedure does not return some obejct type that Task class is expecting ?!

Comment: @Muflix I see only one possible candidate: `database.Connection`

Comment: It's hard to answer, because only database (or database.Connection, if database was disposed) can be null here, and you've shown absolutely nothing about "database" variable. Show the full class definitionm

Comment: @Muflix, We are interested in stack traces of both outer and inner exceptions. I think it woul d be much easier if you provide full data about the exceptions (such as `ex.ToString()`) rather than copying just a few lines out of it.

Comment: @Mufflix `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` does not seem to have a property of `Connection`. There is `DbContext.DataBase` that has a `Connection` but `DBContext.Database` does not have `.Data` that you call in `StartNew`. So again can you post exactly what is `database`? [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: @JSteward ah i get it now, `database` is object of my custom `DatabaseRepository` class but its called with same name as the `Data.Entity.Database` class... `DatabaseRepository database = new DatabaseRepository();` I updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `database.Connection.ConnectionString` is **a static string otherwise you cant compile due** to a "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property".

With that in mind, its not the Connection String that's un-intstatiated because its static... and even if you purposely initialized the static string to Null then the error message would be:

> InnerException = {"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."}

Here is a repro and the error cannot be produced *unless* your GetData Methods are in empty objects:

```
namespace database
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //WORKS!!
        var repro = new database.Data();
        var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => repro.GetData1(3));
        var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => repro.GetData2(5));
        var taskList = new List<Task> { task1, task2 };
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

        //FAILS WITH ERROR REPORTED!!
        repro = null;
        var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => repro.GetData1(3));
        var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => repro.GetData2(5));
        var taskList = new List<Task> { task1, task2 };
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    }
}

class Data
{
    private string connectionString = "Server=.;Database=CRUD_Sample;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing = True;";
    public DataTable GetData1(int Id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_CustomerbyID", sqlcon))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@id", Value = Id });
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }

    public DataTable GetData2(int Id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_CustomerbyID", sqlcon))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@id", Value = Id });
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
}
```

## Debugging

How do you find the source of a NullReferenceException? Apart from looking at the exception itself - the key is a NRE will be thrown exactly at the location where it occurs then you hover your mouse over the variables on the Line Of Code and see which object is null.

Comment: thank you, this works for me in the separate console project, but i am not able to replicate this solution to the project i am working on.. but i dont see any differences yet :/ I tried initialize again the reporistory `DataRepository data = new DataRepository(new System.Data.Entity.DbContext(@"connection string.").Database);` and run `data.GetData1(1)` but it crash in `Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());` line.. if i execute it without `Task` block it works.

Comment: @Muflix, have you tried Jeremy's debugging suggestion? What's the result? Which object is null?

Comment: Put BreakPoints in the `GetData()` methods and the code control (yellow debugging line) will halt when the `Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());` call fires/executes. Then step through each method (freeze one thread in the Debug>Threads Window for ease of debugging) and then you will be able to see `database.Data` object is null. Why it's null I'm guessing is config, run through a simple sample that works with EF and spot the difference.

Comment: yes, i finally found the error! The problem was that in the project I also have the `@user` parameter as mandatory parameter for all the procedures but it is using the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` which is `null` when triggered in the `async` mode.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

`Task.WaitAll` is causing the current thread to block until everything has completed. Use `Task.WhenAll` so as not to tie up the other threads while waiting for the tasks to complete.

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => database.Data.GetData1(1));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => database.Data.GetData2(2));

var taskList = new List<Task> { task1, task2 };

await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());

var result1 = await task1;
var result2 = await task2;
```

Original Answer. (Still applicable)

Based on the additional information provided in the comment, I am making assumptions about the class encapsulating the code in question. It is possible that the `database.Connection` is going out of scope when executed in parallel which may be causing the NRE. Extract the connection string earlier in the life cycle of the object and reuse it when getting the data.

```
 public class MyDataClass {

    string connectionString;
    private Database database;

    public MyDataClass(DbContext context) {
        this.database = context.Database;
        connectionString = database.Connection.ConnectionString;
    }

    public DataTable GetData1(int Id) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        using (var sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetData1", sqlcon)) {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@id", Value = Id });

                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public DataTable GetData2(int Id) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        using (var sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetData2", sqlcon)) {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@id", Value = Id });

                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i tried it but the error is the same, i updated my question with this scenario.

Comment: @Muflix does it make a difference if you use `WhenAll` instead of wait all? I believe that is the root of the problem. The wait all is causing other threads  to block.

Comment: I changed code to `Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());` and it does not throw any error but in the database profiler i dont see any database hit. When i changed code to `await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());` the following error appear `The await operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the async modifier and changing its return type to Task<ActionResult>` because my repository procedures do not returns `Task` object.

Comment: @Muflix show the code that encapsulates the code in the OP. that message makes sense. this is a case of mixing async and sync code.